# Sync everything from google drive business to another business account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, storage, google-drive-shared-drive

Requirements:

- I have two business workspace account with domain A and B
- I need to sync everything in the drive-in domain A to domain B automatically (if instant sync is impossible,    once per day is also acceptable)

  - reason: just for back up if account A is down for some unexpected reasons

Is there any way that I could do this? ( either by coding with api or using existing service )

=================================================================

- why the already provided answer isn't satisfactory?

  - "Perhaps there are alternatives" is not a precise answer"
  - logging in to multiple accounts in google drive for desktop is not a solution. It simply mounts two drive to the pc.

Comment: Does sharing a folder work for you? Have you thought of using the Drive for desktop tool to sync both Drives to->from a folder? What is your use case. Please be more detailed.

Comment: @Aerials which part of the question makes you confused? I think it is well defined already

Comment: @Aerials drive for desktop doesnt work for 2 accounts

Comment: Nowadays Google Drive for Desktop support multiple accounts.

Comment: There is no canonical solution for this (at lease none that I know of). But you can try experimenting with Drive API Push Notifications, they might prove useful in building a solution that meets your requirements.

Comment: You may also try [web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web?hl=en) to create a makeshift api in Domain A to give access to Domain B. Why doesn't simple folder sharing work for you -  Move everything in drive A to a main folder and share it to domain B?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to explain why the already provided answer isn't satisfactory for you.

Comment: "reason: just for back up if account A is down for some unexpected reasons" - Companies with over 30,000 employees use Google Drive and even they don't prepare for this. There is an SLA, there are certifications, there is data redundancy... if one account goes down, most likely the other will also.

Comment: The combination of Drive API and Drive Activity API will do the trick, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

First off let me state that there is nothing out of the box that will let you do this.  As you requested possible coding solutions.

I have done something like this in the past, just not with workspace accounts. TBH it would be easer with workspace.

If I was going to do it again with Workspace accounts here is what I would do.   This assumes that i have admin access on both workspace domains or have access to the admin of that domain.

This can be done in any server sided programming language, there are client libraries for most that support service accounts,  C#, php, python and even node.js.

I would create service accounts credentials on Google developer console.   Then i would have the service account added as users on both work space accounts giving them access to the drive account.  Techinally as this is a one way sync from A to B it the user in Workspace A only needs read access however we will need read / write access to Workspace B.

After that you have access.

Then it will be a matter of programing.

I would select all files and Drive A, and then compare them to Drive B.  There are a number of ways of comparing if something has been changed or not.   If the file was changed i would preform an update, if the file has been created i would insert it.

Things get tricky with delete.  As you would then need to select everything on drive B and see if it exists in A if it does not then the file should then be deleted.

its all doable its just a matter of comparing everything.  This could be set up as a cron job easily.

## What I have done previously

As you have requested `expect a working method instead of saying it is possible without any prove and reference`

It would not be possible to give you a fully working method as you have requested as I don't know the programming language you will be using, nor do i have access to the structure of your drive accounts.

Also Stack Overflow is not a coding service, but i am happy to give you a bit of design headstart.

This is the general idea of what I have done in the past.

```
file.list from drive A
    Loop though each file
         Compaire file from A to file from B
               If file does not exist
                     File.insert to file B
               If file does exist
                     Either check for change or just do file.update

File.list from drive B
      Loop though each file
          Compaire file from b to files from A
                Does file not exist
                       Delete from b
```

- [Google drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk)
- [Service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)
- [Domain wide deligation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)

Comment: You consider it too easily. Drive has a directory structure. Also, the whole directory tree is huge, when you are listing the files, some might already have changed.   And the time complexity is huge,   it is at least O(n_square)

Comment: As I mentored I have done this before for a client. How easy it was is relative to the developers experience i guess.   It could be related to the fact that i have twelve years experience with google apis and twenty five years of programming experience.  Its really not that hard of a problem to solve.   but knowing big o notation doesn't help much in solving problems but thats just my opinion.

Comment: You talk about how many years of experience you have but I am actually saying your answer is not useful. Since "everyone knows that syncing is to create a file if not yet created. Delete a file if already deleted in the source." I have tried to retrieve the whole tree structure before, it takes a very long time. You seem to have 0 experience in google drive api.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this, but it's doable. There are a couple of steps that you need to complete.

1. **Do the initial sync** between two drives. That will require running a script that will re-create the folder structure in your drive B and copy all the files there. If the volume is high, you will need to to make sure your script bypasses the maximum authorized script runtime (probably 30 minutes in your case). I have built such a solution in the past. I also have [a story on bypassing the maximum execution time on Medium](https://medium.com/geekculture/bypassing-the-maximum-script-runtime-in-google-apps-script-e510aa9ae6da?source=friends_link&sk=ca2b3c4d2fa429e02ba5f81a94d0c780) that tackles a similar problem if you are interested.
2. **Regularly sync all changes** with the [Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/). This way you don't copy everything with each sync, but only those files and folders that were either updated, deleted or created.

This is no easy endeavor, but definitely can be done.